# How can i strictly prove this conclusion

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

$a,b\in R^n$. For all the $x \in R^n$ that satisfy $x\cdot a \geq 0$, will also satisfy $x\cdot b\geq 0$.
Show that there exist a non-negative real number $\lambda$, that makes $b=\lambda a$

sorry about my English :(

Comment: **Hint**: $b=\lambda a+ \mu v$, with $v\cdot a=0$ and $v\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_1 \in \mathbb R^n$ such as $a_1 \cdot a  =0$. Then, since $x \cdot a \geq 0 \Rightarrow x \cdot b \geq 0$, we have $a_1 \cdot b \geq 0$. Also, $ (-a_1) \cdot a \geq 0$ and therefore $(-a_1) \cdot b \geq 0$. However $(-a_1) \cdot b = -(a_1 \cdot b)$. It follows $a_1 \cdot b = 0$.

Since $b$ is orthogonal to every vector orthogonal to $a$, we conclude that $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb R : b = \lambda a$.

Now, since $a \cdot a \geq 0$, we have that $a \cdot b \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow (\lambda a) \cdot a \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \lambda \geq 0$

Comment: I think I figured it out by using the method of your answer and supposing $b=\lambda a+\mu v,(v\cdot a=0, v\neq 0)$. Thx

Comment: @XuGalla that's basically the answer, however, you have to suppose $n-1$ vectors orthogonal to $a$ since you are in $\mathbb R^n$. Other than that, no difference.

Comment: @Dosidis very beautiful proof!!! But I think if you say $(-a_1).a_1=0$ it will more explicit. Because there is no difference and $x.a=0$ will also satisfy $x.b\ge 0$. This way the reader thinks you've supposed $a_1$ orthogonal to $a$ but $-a_1$ may be not orthogonal to $a$

Comment: @sepideh Thank you. We use both $a_1 \cdot a = 0$ and $(-a_1) \cdot a = 0$, and since they are equivalent (each implies the other), you can assume either one of them.